# Run I\O bunch threads in asynchronous manner

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have tons of WCF service calls. Simply:

```
foreach (var node in tree.Nodes) {
    // some preparing code here
    ....

    treeView.TocStorageInstance.UpdateNode(node) //network call
}
```

I'd like to parallel all these network calls which are executing one by one - as I see in the Fiddler.

Trying the next approach is not successful:

```
    var nodesToUpdate = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var node in tree.Nodes) {
        // some preparing code here
        ....
        nodesToUpdate.Add(await Task.Run(() => treeView.TocStorageInstance.UpdateNode(node)));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(nodesToUpdate);
```

All calls still execute one-by-one in `foreach` statement.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: you don't need await in this case. Just add Task (w/o await) to the list and Task.WhenAll(nodesToUpdate)

Comment: @Leonid. The same I did, but during debugging I see, that async code executes before Task.WhenAll(). And finally Task.WhenAll() completes with last item in iterator.

Comment: In you code you 1st wait for task to complete (await) and only after it you add that task to the list. So no parallel work.

Comment: In this example you can just build the tasks with linq and await them in one line...